# How to make Boostrap Navbar elements inline?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, navbar

[image: The image is with border on every element in the body, the navbar is the upper blue part]I actually don't know whats wrong here is it some bootstrap error in the code do i have the wrong version or something?
I think align-items-center should do it i don't know why it doesn't. And please don't tell me to make the elements display:inline or inline-block, it does not work.
Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import logo from "../logo.svg";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { ButtonContainer } from "./Button";

export class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavWrapper className="navbar navbar-dark ">
        <Link to="/">
          <img src={logo} alt="store" className="navbar-brand " />
        </Link>
        <ul className="navbar-nav align-items-center">
          <li className="nav-item ">
            <Link to="/" className="nav-link">
              products
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <Link to="/cart" className="ml-auto">
          <ButtonContainer>
            <span className="mr-2">
              <i className="fas fa-cart-plus" />
            </span>
            my cart
          </ButtonContainer>
        </Link>
      </NavWrapper>
    );
  }
}

const NavWrapper = styled.nav`
  background: var(--mainBlue);
  .nav-link {
    color: var(--mainWhite);
    fontsize: 1.3rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }
`;

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @JasonTowne v4.0.0-alpha.6

Comment: Why such an old alpha version?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for taking your time, i just reinstalled bootstrap and it works...